# Ajax request on wordpress returns 404 error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

On my function.php file on my custom theme folder I have this:

```
function getPrices(){
    $price = get_post_meta($_REQUEST["post_id"], "price_one", true);
    $results['price'] = $price;
    $results = json_encode($results);
    die($results);
}

    add_action('wp_ajax_getPrices', 'getPrices');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getPrices', 'getPrices');
```

and on the js file I had this:

```
$('ul.people_adult li').click(function(){
var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType : "json"
                    url: "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    data: {
                        action: 'getPrices',
                        post_id: post_id
                    },
                    complete:function(data){
                        console.log(data.price);
                    }
                    });
});
```

When I click the following error message: 
`POST http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 404 (Not Found)`

Also when I alert the returned data it shows object Object but when I log it to console it shows all the html code of the responded page.

Any ideas ??

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you visit the URL in the browser?

Comment: What is the base url of your site?

Comment: Thanks guys. Your questions make me find that the url is wrong. I am searching 4 hours now without even notice it. Now get a response but I can't get access to the data json object. It says that is undefined.I put also dataType : "json" to the js file but again I can't take the value. EDIT: I edit my code.

Comment: I try this on the console of chrome and I got these responses : typeof (data)
"undefined"
typeof (data.price)
ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: Ok... I had a typo mistake. Shouldn't code that late. Thanks!! I update my code to the working one.

Comment: Please , if you can describe your mistake as an ANSWER so you could accept it and mark it as closed , it would help other people to know that the issue is resolved .

Comment: Thanks didn't know I can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big problem was the bad URL I was providing and for some reason couldn't notice until Jackson and cointilt mention it.

Also I had typo errors in my function.php file.

Here is the answer to my problem.

```
function getPrices(){
    $the_id = $_REQUEST["post_id"];
    $results[] = get_post_meta($the_id, "price_one", true);
    $results[] = get_post_meta($the_id, "price_two", true);
    $results[] = get_post_meta($the_id, "price_three", true);
    $results[] = get_post_meta($the_id, "price_four", true);
    $results[] = get_post_meta($the_id, "price_five", true);
    $results[] = get_post_meta($the_id, "price_six", true);
    $results[] = get_post_meta($the_id, "price_seven", true);
    $results[] = get_post_meta($the_id, "price_eight", true);
    $results = json_encode($results);
    die($results);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_getPrices', 'getPrices');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getPrices', 'getPrices');
```

and on the js file

```
$('ul.people_adult li').click(function(){
    var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            dataType : "json",
                            url: "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                            data: {
                                action: 'getPrices',
                                post_id: post_id
                            },
                            success:function(response){
                                $("#price_est_person").html(response[0]);
/*Do some stuff with response[1], response[2 etc]*/
                            }
                            });
    });
```